# RavenDB: Method not supported: All

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm getting the exception: `Method not supported: All` on the last line, below:

```
private static Expression<Func<InstallationSummary, bool>> GetWhereClause(ApplicationServer appServer, ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup appWithGroup)
{
    // If we're getting matches that include CustomVariableGroups (CVGs), then the number of CVGs and the IDs must match.
    return summary => summary.ApplicationServerId == appServer.Id &&
                    summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.ApplicationId == appWithGroup.Application.Id &&
                    summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup != null &&
                    summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds != null &&
                    summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Count == appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Count &&
                    summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.All(appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Contains);
}
```

Is there another option to use instead of `All()`, or do I need to bring back the results and loop through them in memory?

```
public class ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup : EntityBase
{
    // More code here
    public List<string> CustomVariableGroupIds { get; set; }
    // More code here
}
```

Comment: Show your `InstallationSummary` class so we can see what `CustomVariableGroupIds` is.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: `All` can always be replaced by `Any` with a negated argument. If that's not supported, you can replace it by `Where` followed by `Any()`. Would that possibly help?

Comment: [Apparently `Any` and `All` are not supported inside expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). Perhaps calling the Linq extension method manually would do the trick (i.e. transform the `All` into a plain `Call` -- though obviously this would require things to be in memory)?

Comment: Could you retry your code by using a lambda expression in `All` instead? The way I see it, you are using the `Enumerable.All` extension method, whereas the extension method that has a chance of working is `Queryable.All`. (That is, try writing `.All(cvg => appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Contains(cvg))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (albeit possibly inefficient) is that you can always pull the query into memory and then perform `.All` (or any other Linq method) because the records are already loaded into the application space.

To do this in most cases, you just add [`.AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your `IQueyable` object. Because extension methods are defined statically against the specific type, this means you'll be using the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension methods, all of which use a `foreach`, and thus the query evaluates in-memory.

In this case, it may take some restructuring since you're returning a where clause - such an implementation would have to attach this behaviour to the building of the whole query.

Comment: I had to go with the in-memory approach because RavenDB wouldn't work with `All()` or the negated `Any()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate All to not Any like:

```
     summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.All(appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Contains);
```

to

```
     !summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Any(x => !appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Contains(x));
```

Comment: "All" is not the same as "not any" unless you also negate the inner expression. Example: "No single apple is blue" does not mean "all apples are blue", but "no single apple is a colour other than blue" does.

Comment: While not very intuitive (because of the multiple !s), it's at least still just that one line of code. Let me see if I can get that to work...

Comment: What's cool about this answer is that ReSharper asks me if I want to simplify it and convert it to the code that Jean provided. I can't, because RavenDB doesn't support it, but it's at least an indication that it's equivalent code.

Comment: Apparently RavenDB doesn't allow this approach either. I get: `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot process negated Any(), see RavenDB-732 http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-732`

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see is that you are not using the correct overloading of `.All`.

That is, you are using `appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Contains` which is a method group, and as such can be converted to delegate type `Func<..., bool>`, but not to the `Expression<Func<..., bool>>` that is required by [`Queryable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534754.aspx). Because of that, you are actually using [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541.aspx), which cannot be supported by a LINQ query provider that wants to translate the query expression.

However, you can write your `All` clause as a lambda expression instead, and then the correct overload will be called:

```
summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.All(cvg => appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroupIds.Contains(cvg));
```

Comment: I tried that and I still get `Method not supported: All`. Perhaps RavenDB simply doesn't support this yet.

Comment: I am also realizing that my explanation is slightly wrong - that is, because `CustomVariableGroupIds` is probably not an `IQueryable`, `Queryable.All` cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

In Raven.Client 3.0 there is a `ContainsAll` extension method which seem to be what you are searching for.

```
namespace Raven.Client.Linq
{
    public static class RavenQueryableExtensions
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Implementation of the Contains ALL operatior
        public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> items);
    }
}
```

Exemple:

```
string[] parts
var query = session.Query<Foo>()
    .Where(s => s.Keywords.ContainsAll(parts));
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope it helps someone. I'm not in a position to try this now.